# How to get the Name, MIME Type and Content of a VWAttachment in Filenet P8?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

I have been trying to get the name, MIME type and content of a VWAttachment in FileNet P8. The content should be a byte array or an input stream.

UPDATE:

`String name = attachment.getAttachmentName();`

Gives me the name of `VWAttachment`. And let's say by looking at the file extension I can decide proper MIME type. I need to know how can I get the content of the attachment in an `InputStream`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the information in the VWAttachment object to fetch the correct document from the Content Engine.

for example:

```
com.filenet.api.core.Domain domain = (...you need to get this);
VWAttachment vwAttachment = (...you already have this);

ObjectStore objectStore = Factory.ObjectStore.getInstance(domain, vwAttachment.getLibraryName());
VersionSeries vs = Factory.VersionSeries.fetchInstance(objectStore, new Id( vwAttachment.getId()), null);
Document document = (Document) vs.get_CurrentVersion();

ContentTransfer contentTransfer = (ContentTransfer) document.get_ContentElements().get(0);
InputStream inputStream = contentTransfer.accessContentStream();
```